# Bug in substitution decryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, substitution

```
import random
orig=list(range(1,65))
temp_orig= [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
    [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
    [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
    [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
    [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]
```

ip= [[40, 24, 9, 41, 42, 56, 43, 45],
    [4, 23, 21, 60, 35, 6, 59, 0],
    [36, 53, 32, 16, 7, 37, 17, 18],
    [10, 62, 61, 38, 29, 34, 31, 25],
    [54, 57, 51, 49, 39, 3, 50, 30],
    [11, 46, 33, 27, 44, 15, 13, 48],
    [12, 58, 1, 26, 47, 20, 28, 52],
    [19, 55, 2, 63, 22, 8, 14, 5]]

ipinv=[[15, 50, 58, 37, 8, 63, 13, 20],
    [61, 2, 24, 40, 48, 46, 62, 45],
    [19, 22, 23, 56, 53, 10, 60, 9],
    [1, 31, 51, 43, 54, 28, 39, 30],
    [18, 42, 29, 12, 16, 21, 27, 36],
    [0, 3, 4, 6, 44, 7, 41, 52],
    [47, 35, 38, 34, 55, 17, 32, 57],
    [5, 33, 49, 14, 11, 26, 25, 59]]

print "\n\nOriginal position of Bits:"
for i in range(len(ipinv)):
    print "\t",temp_orig[i]
print "\n\nInitial Permutation Table"
for i in range(len(ipinv)):
    print "\t",ip[i]
print "\n\nInverse Initail permutation Table"
for i in range(len(ipinv)):
    print "\t",ipinv[i]

print "\nRound 1:Initial Permutation"

plaintext=list(raw_input("\n\tEnter not more than 8 char:"))

l=len(plaintext)
for i in range(8,len(plaintext)):
   del plaintext[l-1+8-i]

print "\n\tPlain text:",plaintext,"\n"

for i in range(8):
    plaintext[i]=list(bin(ord(plaintext[i])).zfill(8))
    print "\t",plaintext[i]

ip1=temp_orig
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ip1[i][j]=plaintext[(ip[i][j])/8][(ip[i][j])%8]

print "\nEnciphered list:"
for i in range(8):
    print "\t",ip1[i]
print "\n73\n",ip1[7][3],"\n73"

ip1_d=temp_orig

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ip1_d[i][j]=ip1[(ipinv[i][j])/8][(ipinv[i][j])%8]
        print ip1[7][3],"ip1_d",[i],[j],"=ip1[",(ipinv[i][j])/8,"][",(ipinv[i][j])%8,"]"
        #print "ip1_d",[i],[j],"=",ip1[(ipinv[i][j])/8][(ipinv[i][j])%8]

print "\nDeciphered list:"
for i in range(8):
    print "\t",ip1_d[i]

The de sunstitution becomes wrong, just for example i tried printing `ip1[7][3]` and all of a sudden it changes value when `i=7` and `j=3` without any assignment to ip1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do `ip1=temp_orig` a few times. That tells me that you probably think this copies the `temp_orig` list - it does not. You have to explicitly copy the list here:

```
ip1=[list(row) for row in temp_orig]
```

and so on. Your code just gives new names to `temp_orig` but still modifies the `temp_orig` list.

I think this is the most chaotic code I've seen in a while. You should start thinking more in terms of transformations of your data instead of juggling indices like this. I still have no idea what your code does or how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot .  it works. i was creating a new list with two oops for ip1 and ip1_d . but thought copying the previous list will do so and also reduce the code....but the method i copied was wrong.....